# Inner query slower than full subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery

Can anybody provide an example or explanation as to why a query of form:

```
SELECT a.col0
FROM a INNER JOIN b on a.id = b.id
WHERE b.cond = 0
```

would be slower than:

```
SELECT c.col1 
FROM c 
WHERE c.col2 IN (
    SELECT a.col0
    FROM a INNER JOIN b on a.id = b.id
    WHERE b.cond = 0
) AND c.col2 = 0
```

Forgive me if the syntax isn't correct, but the general idea is that the innermost query is actually slower than the subquery containing the innermost query.

Comment: Because the data from the inner query is cached when you run the outer one? Because the optimiser chooses a different access path? Because the statistics were different when the two queries were parsed? If you have a real example then look at the two execution plans.

Comment: Or maybe because there are no rows in c where col2 = 0? Or maybe the first query returns a lot of rows whereas the 2nd returns a small amount, so less time taken to return the results to you?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, there could be several reasons for this. You need to have a good knowledge of database optimization including how you DBMS (database management system) handles datasets.

A couple obvious reasons:

a) Indexes play a BIG part in database optimization. It doesn't seem like this is affecting the differences in these queries

b) Caching is a subject that many databases take into account. If you ran the first query (as above) and then ran the second one (which is very similar to and is using the same table as the prior query) on the same opened connection, well likely the table was cached and it was able to query it faster.

My immediate assumption from your example above is the situation of caching.

I suggest you give it a minute to let your cache clear and try running your queries the other way around (run the 2nd one before you 1st one) and you may find that it is vice verse.

You can also check the execution plans.